Delta Lake table write without schema enforcement
I have a Delta Lake table partitioned by hour. The table schema includes:

colA (string type)
colB (int type)
colC (struct type)

When I perform a historical load, all partitions are populated correctly. However, during my hourly job to write new data into this table, there are certain hours where colC is undefined. This causes the inferred data type for colC to differ from the existing schema in the Delta Lake table.
Additionally, I prefer not to define the schema during the data read of raw files, as the schema can evolve over time.
Example Scenario:
Historical Load:

Hour 1: colA = “value1”, colB = 100, colC = {“field1”: “data1”, “field2”: 10}
Hour 2: colA = “value2”, colB = 200, colC = {“field1”: “data2”, “field2”: 20}

Hourly Job:

Hour 3: colA = “value3”, colB = 300, colC = undefined
Hour 4: colA = “value4”, colB = 400, colC = {“field1”: “data4”, “field2”: 40}

Problem:
For Hour 3, colC is undefined, leading to a mismatch in the inferred schema.
Question: How can I handle this situation where colC is sometimes undefined, without defining a fixed schema during the data read?
Example code:
inferred_schema = spark.read.json(df_raw.rdd.map(lambda x: x['Body'])).schema
df = df_raw.withColumn('BodyNew', from_json(col(), inferred_schema))
opts = {
    "mergeSchema": "true",
    "overwriteSchema": "false",
    "partitionOverwriteMode":"dynamic"
    }
df.write.partitionBy("hour")\
    .mode("overwrite")\
    .format("delta")\
    .options(**opts)\
    .save(path)
# above code works when I read data for a big date range
# but fails when I run it for few selective hours, 
# because for those hours some columns are undefined
# which lead to inferred schema to be different.


You may consider reading the existing table schema and attaching it to the input dataframe. The rough code can be something like the one below.
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_json

existing_table_name = "<add the output table name>"
inferred_schema = spark.read.table(existing_table_name).schema

df = df_raw.withColumn('BodyNew', from_json(col('Body'), inferred_schema))

opts = {
    "mergeSchema": "true",
    "overwriteSchema": "false",
    "partitionOverwriteMode": "dynamic"
}

# Step 4: Write the DataFrame to a Delta table
df.write ...


but this will not support schema evolution?
if in future some new fields are added, they won't be added to the delta table.

In that case, you should merge df_raw schema with inferred_schema then apply it on df = df_raw.withColumn('BodyNew', from_json(col('Body'), inferred_schema))

can you suggest how to do such schema merge?
